# What are the benefits of using Flask's logger instead of your own?

Tags: python, flask

I saw the warning that my question appears to be subjective - I would like to clarify that my question is what is the purpose and what are the benefits of using the Flask provided logger, *as stated by the library authors*, which can be objectively verified.

I checked the documentation on [logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#logging) and on [Application Errors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/errorhandling/#application-errors) but couldn't spot a list of benefits.

---

There are two ways to log in flask: using the `app.logger` provided by flask, or by rolling your own `logger`.

Using the logger provided by flask:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

app.logger.debug("Hello World")
```

Or Using your own:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug("Hello World")
```

Using the flask provided logger `app.logger` applies a custom format to the message that looks pretty. Unless `app.debug=True`, `info` and `warn` messages are not captured.

However there is a burden of typing `app.logger` instead of `logger`.

What are the benefits of using the Flask provided logger - from the Flask author's point of view?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your code, the Flask version of logging requires only one line (`app.debug = True`) where the alternative requires four. Since you're already using that framework, it makes sense to take advantage of it and trim down the amount of code you have to write.

As far as the perceived drawback - having to type `app.logger` rather than simply `logger` - remember that you can just rebind it to a new name with `logger = app.logger`, negating that single disadvantage while remaining shorter and simpler than a custom logger.

Comment: That was `app.logger`, not `api.logger`, correct?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - Yes.